# How to catch system events when a program is being updated and robotize routine steps when you update software?

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file

I'm a support engineer for an accounting program. The program runs under Windows.

I have to update many of this accounting software bases daily. I mean the software is always the same. But users may have, say, 50 informational bases installed. Each base needs updating. It may be some outsorcing company which does bookkeeping for its clients or something. So, for every client they install a special informational base which I have to update.

I would like to robotize my routine operations somehow. 
I mean I have to: start each program, in the menu select updating process, seek for updates in a directory, press next, confirm that I have read the instruction notes, confirm that I have backuped the data, then Next, Next and Finish. Then in the main menu I have to restart the program, then agree that the software has been purchased legally. Then restart again. Make another backup copy. Then launch testing process and select several options (always typical in a typical case). Then I have to wait for the test to pass. Then go on to another informational base.

The software developer doesn't provide us with any launch options for silent mode or something. Well, it tkes from 20 minutes to 1 hour to update one informational base.

I have got acquainted with several programming languages. Like Java, C#, some scripting languages. But I have never written a batch file.

Well, I'm just wondering if you could recommend me which technology/language can I use to automatize this if it is humanly possible. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to robotize my routine operations somehow.

We have a word for that: automation. :)

> I mean I have to: start each program, in the menu select updating
>   process, seek for updates in a directory, press next, confirm that I
>   have read the instruction notes, confirm that I have backuped the
>   data, then Next, Next and Finish.

[AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) might be able to help with this part.

> The software developer doesn't provide us with any launch options for
>   silent mode or something.

Have you requested that he do so? The software dev works for you, right? You ought to be able talk with that person's management and get automation support in as a feature request.